PHP Is there a way to check if an exception is a certain TYPE of exception?
I know that it's possible to catch particular types of exceptions in try/catch, for example catch (TypeError $t) or something.
However, I'm trying to see if there is a way to check if Exception $e === TypeError?
The reason for this is, I want to have a different behavior when I get a TypeError vs. when I get all other types of exception, and if I do:
catch (Exception $e) { // do something }
I will ALSO be sending that behavior if $e is a TypeError, which is not what I want.
So basically what I WANT to happen is:
try { 
  // something 
} catch (Exception $e) {
  if ($e !== TypeError) {
     // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}

Is that possible? What's the correct syntax for that? I can't find any clear info as to whether or not that's possible in the docs but maybe I'm looking in the wrong place? Or maybe it's just impossible?

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php

for example catch (TypeError $t) or something - I don't know if I'm missing something, but yes, that's exactly it. You just need to make sure that that's the first case if your catch block(s). Your question sounds like you tried it, but you don't say why it didn't work. TypeError implements Throwable (because it extends Error), which means you can catch it

As well as the linked answer regarding instanceof, perhaps you aren't aware that you can have multiple catch blocks attached to one try, and the first which matches will be executed. It's surprisingly hard to find a good example of this, but this tutorial is reasonable: https://www.phptutorial.net/php-oop/php-try-catch/
